# Change sinfo message with number of entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, salesforce, visualforce

I'm new to datatables. I want to customize sinfo message from "Showing START to END of TOTAL entries" to "Showing START to END of first 1000 entries", if the total number of entries exceed 1000. and if the total number of entries is less than 1000 then it should display "Showing START to END of TOTAL entries". I'm using datatable in salesforce.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to sort it out by calling `infoCallback` function in table's js file.

```
$("#example-table").dataTable({
     "infoCallback": function( settings, start, end, max, total, pre ) {
        if (total == 0) {
             start = 0;
        }
        if (total > 999) {
            return "Showing " +start +" to "+ end + " of first 1000 entries";
        } else {
            return "Showing " +start +" to "+ end + " of "+total +" entries";
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of depends upon your set up. If you're using something like [this](http://drmsite.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/datatables-for-salesforce-dt2apex-and.html) then you can alter the the `DataTableController` class to return a string in the `Response` `recordsTotal` and append 1st (or first) if result is less than 1000... if not then I guess it's a question of altering the drawCallback and interrogating the text in the `dataTables_info` class. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was making some changes and adding some conditions in jquery.datatables.js file.